# Updating classification probability in logistic regression for past errors

Tags: logistic, posterior

At time $t-1$ I have a matrix of design variables $X_{t-1}$ and a binary outcome vector $Y_{t-1}$. Using logistic regression, I obtain the model:

$$\hat{p}_{t-1}(y|x)$$

plugging new data $X_t$ gives me an estimate of $\hat{Y}_t$. So far, so good.

Now at time $t$, after computing $\hat{Y}_t$, I also receive the *true* values $y_t$ for a small *selected* subset of the observations. Selected here means only for some of the observations for which $\hat{p}_{t-1}(y_t|x_t)>\tau$ for some $\tau$ close to 1.

My question is: how can I use the information in this new data to update my estimates of $\hat{p}_{t-1}(y|x)$ to better classify incoming data ($\hat{y}_{t+1}|x_{t+1}$)?